# Substitute values across different data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, substitution

I have the following code for 4 dataframes. The last column of each has only 2 values, either zero ("0") or an id, which is the same within every `df`, but differs between every `df`.

How can substitute all zeros in the `id` columns for all the same ids?

As example, change `df1` from:

```
     year    counts    id
 1   2015    0         0
 2   2016    0         0
 3   2017    7         Fg4s5
 4   2018    8         Fg4s5
 5   2019    5         0
 6   2020    12        Fg4s5
```

to:

```
     year    counts    id
 1   2015    0         Fg4s5
 2   2016    0         Fg4s5
 3   2017    7         Fg4s5
 4   2018    8         Fg4s5
 5   2019    5         Fg4s5
 6   2020    12        Fg4s5
```

Same for other `df`s with their ids.

**Code for dataframes:**

```
 df1 <- data.frame(
   year = c(2015:2020),
   counts = c(0, 0, 7, 8, 5, 12),
   id = c(0, 0, "Fg4s5", "Fg4s5", 0, "Fg4s5")
 )
 df2 <- data.frame(
   year = c(2014:2020),
   counts = c(1, 5, 9, 2, 2, 19, 3),
   id = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "Qd8a2", "Qd8a2")
 )
 df3 <- data.frame(
   year = c(2016:2020),
   counts = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 6),
   id = c(0, 0, "Wk9l4", "Wk9l4", "Wk9l4")
 )
 df4 <- data.frame(
   year = c(2014:2020),
   counts = c(0, 0, 8, 1, 9, 12, 23),
   id = c(0, "Rd7q0", 0, 0, "Rd7q0", "Rd7q0", "Rd7q0")
 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the dataframes in a list and change the value in `id` columns using `lapply` :

```
list_df <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)

lapply(list_df, function(x) {
  transform(x, id = replace(id, id == 0, id[id != '0'][1]))
}) -> list_df

list_df

#[[1]]
#  year counts    id
#1 2015      0 Fg4s5
#2 2016      0 Fg4s5
#3 2017      7 Fg4s5
#4 2018      8 Fg4s5
#5 2019      5 Fg4s5
#6 2020     12 Fg4s5

#[[2]]
#  year counts    id
#1 2014      1 Qd8a2
#2 2015      5 Qd8a2
#3 2016      9 Qd8a2
#4 2017      2 Qd8a2
#5 2018      2 Qd8a2
#6 2019     19 Qd8a2
#7 2020      3 Qd8a2

#[[3]]
#  year counts    id
#1 2016      0 Wk9l4
#2 2017      0 Wk9l4
#3 2018      0 Wk9l4
#4 2019      0 Wk9l4
#5 2020      6 Wk9l4

#[[4]]
#  year counts    id
#1 2014      0 Rd7q0
#2 2015      0 Rd7q0
#3 2016      8 Rd7q0
#4 2017      1 Rd7q0
#5 2018      9 Rd7q0
#6 2019     12 Rd7q0
#7 2020     23 Rd7q0
```

To put them in separate dataframes.

```
names(list_df) <- paste0('df', 1:4)
list2env(list_df, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Nice, thank you! How can I apply the changes so that df1-df4 are each still a separate df1-df4?

Comment: Updated the answer for that.

Comment: Wow, amazing. Saves me so much time! thank you.

Answer (score 2):

using `purrr::map`

```
map(list(df1, df2, df3, df4),  ~ .x %>% mutate(id = first(id[id != "0"])))

[[1]]
  year counts    id
1 2015      0 Fg4s5
2 2016      0 Fg4s5
3 2017      7 Fg4s5
4 2018      8 Fg4s5
5 2019      5 Fg4s5
6 2020     12 Fg4s5

[[2]]
  year counts    id
1 2014      1 Qd8a2
2 2015      5 Qd8a2
3 2016      9 Qd8a2
4 2017      2 Qd8a2
5 2018      2 Qd8a2
6 2019     19 Qd8a2
7 2020      3 Qd8a2

[[3]]
  year counts    id
1 2016      0 Wk9l4
2 2017      0 Wk9l4
3 2018      0 Wk9l4
4 2019      0 Wk9l4
5 2020      6 Wk9l4

[[4]]
  year counts    id
1 2014      0 Rd7q0
2 2015      0 Rd7q0
3 2016      8 Rd7q0
4 2017      1 Rd7q0
5 2018      9 Rd7q0
6 2019     12 Rd7q0
7 2020     23 Rd7q0
```

Comment: Great solution! Gracias.